# Esperar x segundos e mostrar um submit

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma de quando um usuário entra numa página, o JavaScript esperar 20 segundos e após esperar esses 20 segundos mostrar um *submit* em tempo real?

Ou seja, o usuário entraria na página, esperava 20 segundos, após esperar esses 20 segundos em tempo real na página aparecia o *submit*.

Comment: Deixe um button type submit hidden e use a função do JavaScript settimeinterval passando o tempo em ms para remover o hidden do button

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu o problema, marque ela como aceita. Veja em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 8):

Você pode usar a função `setTimeout()` e jQuery para resolver seu problema facilmente.

#### No HTML

- `style="display:none"` - fará o botão ficar invisível no inicio

#### No JavaScript

- `$('#idSubmit')` - representa o seletor do seu elemento
- `.show()` - representa a função que no caso é exibir
- `3000` é o tempo em milisegundos que voce deseja esperar, mantive um tempo de 3 segundos para o exemplo não demorar muito mas voce pode colocar o tempo que quiser
  20 segundos seria `20000`

#### Veja o codigo abaixo

```js
$('#idSubmit').hide();

setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#idSubmit').show();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="id" >
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"> <br>
    
    Last name:<br> 
    <input type="text" name="lastname"> <br>
     
    <input id="idSubmit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Existe alguma de quando um usuário entra numa página, o JavaScript esperar 20 segundos e após esperar esses 20 segundos mostrar um submit em tempo real?

Para executar uma função após um determinado tempo, utilize a função [`.setTimeout(callback, delay)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

É importante se atentar para o fato de que o parâmetro *delay* é representado em milisegundos, conforme descrição abaixo:

> **delay** is the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) that the function call should be delayed by. If omitted, it defaults to 0. The actual delay may be longer; see Notes below.

Vamos supor que você possui uma função com o nome `minhaFuncao`, e quer executá-la depois de 20 segundos. Nesse caso você utilizaria a seguinte sintaxe:

```
setTimeout(minhaFuncao, 20000);
```

## Exemplo

```js
function showSubmit() {
  document.getElementById('submit-btn').style.display = 'block';
}

setTimeout(showSubmit, 2000);
```

```css
#submit-btn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="submit-btn">
```

Answer (score 3):

No exemplo abaixo, utilizo JQuery devido ao uso da função ready().

Tudo que estiver dentro dessa função será executado somente após o carregamento de todos os objetos da página.

Isso é necessário para evitar dessincronização entre as execuções.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

/**
Tempo em segundos
*/
seconds = 20;

/**
Oculta o botão.
Alternativamente, pode ocultar com CSS também.
*/
$("#btn").hide();

/**
A função setTimeout() cria o delay de execução.
O tempo é medido em milisegundos, por isso, multiplimos por 1000.
*/
setTimeout(function(){$("#btn").show();}, seconds*1000);

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

botão aparece aqui: 
<input type="submit" value="ok" id="btn" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uma correção na explicação: o uso da função `$.ready` não é necessário para evitar a dessincronização. No seu exemplo em especial, ele deve ser utilizado pelo simples fato de o seu botão estar abaixo do bloco de script. Sem o uso do `$.ready` nesse caso, o script seria executado antes mesmo de o botão existir.

Comment: exatamente pela forma como apresentei, se faz necessário.  Há formas diferentes de fazer.  Sem o ready corre risco de haver disparo do settimeout antes de todos os elementos carregarem. O risco é pequeno, mas de qualquer forma é um risco.

Comment: particularmente prefiro não colocar scripts fora do head, especialmente no body.. deixa o codigo esteticamente “sujo”, mas não quer dizer que um eh mais certo do que outro. É questão de escolha do programador e padrões sob o qual se trabalha.

Comment: por isso, discordo do seu comentário, pois coloca o comentário como se fosse correção de um erro. Mas não há erro algum. É um comentário equivocado.

Comment: eu recomendo a leitura dos seguintes materiais: [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) e [Where is the best place to put <script> tags in HTML markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup/24070373#24070373)

Comment: lido com web desde 1998.. chega a ser uma piada me indicar essa matéria.. Aliás, aqui mesmo no SO-pt tem um topico sobre o assunto.. Já que tocou no assunto, não há um melhor local para usar as tags de scripts. Depende de cada caso. Infelizmente muitos interpretam recomendações X para caso Y de forma errada ou ao pé da letra e cria-se esse mito de que deve ser assim, com scripts no body ou ao final do `</html>`.. Mitos baseados em má interpretação e disseminação de informação errônea ou equivocada.. Um exemplo de equívoco, o seu comentário aqui..