# Botão invisível após certo tempo

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Galera, tenho uma página VSL com um botão que direciona para um WhatsApp, porém, queria deixar esse botão invisível por 10 minutos, antes de aparecer, pois passo um vídeo antes. Como posso fazer isso?

Esse, atualmente, é meu botão:

```
button.whats {
        cursor: pointer;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        border-top-right-radius: 25px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #34af23;
    background-color: #34af23;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    align-content: center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    font face: Helvetica;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
```

Comment: para entender melhor.. Você quer que ao usuário acessar a página, de primeira instância o tal botão fique escondido e o vídeo é exibido e após 10 minutos (que é o tempo de reprodução do vídeo), você quer que o vídeo se esconda e exiba o tal botão?

Comment: Assunto triplicado! Aqui um exemplo: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp  --  Tópico relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91709/60601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você vai esconder o botão com a propriedade `display`:

```
button.whats {
 display: none;
}
```

Em seguida um JavaScript para mostrar o botão após 10 minutos:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   setTimeout(function(){
      document.querySelector("button.whats").style.display = "inline-block";
   }, 600000);

});
</script>
```

O valor `600000` (seiscentos mil) são 600 mil milissegundos, que é igual a 10 minutos.

Comment: Muito bom essa dica, parabéns @Sam.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar os [eventos da tag `<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Events) para mostrar e esconder outros elementos na página.

O exemplo a seguir usa os eventos [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event), [`play`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event) e [`pause`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause_event) para mostrar os botões, onde o evento `ended` só é lançado quando o vídeo chega ao fim ou o servidor não retorna mais dados ao player.

```js
let video = document.getElementById('video')
let btnPaused = document.getElementById('show-on-paused')
let btnEnded = document.getElementById('show-on-ended')

function hideOnPause() {
    btnPaused.classList.toggle('hidden', !video.paused)
}

video.addEventListener("pause", hideOnPause)
video.addEventListener("play", hideOnPause)

video.addEventListener("ended", event => {
    btnEnded.classList.toggle('hidden', false)
})
```

```css
section {display: flex}
button.hidden {display: none}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <video id="video" controls muted playsinline autoplay width=250
        src="https://archive.org/download/HorseGallopAnimation/MuybridgeHorseRide.mp4"></video>
    <span class="buttons">
        <button id="show-on-paused" class="hidden">Mostra quando pausado</button>
        <button id="show-on-ended" class="hidden">Mostra quando terminado</button>
    </span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção só com CSS. Repare que ele tem uma animação, e o BTN só vai ficar visível depois de `3s` (3 segundos), mas se vc quiser 10min coloca 600s.

**Execute e espere 3 segundos que o btn vai aparecer!**

```css
.btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: btn 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes btn {
  0% {
  visibility: hidden;    
  }
  99% {
  visibility: hidden;    
  }
  100% {
  visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#teste" class="btn">BTN</a>
```